# How can I get the value from a child Dictionary created with json data

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a json file that looks like this

```
{"data":
[0]
    [{"type":"user",
    "id":"e4b167ba-b244-4c32-9566-00492c6d437e",
"attributes":{
    "externalId":"53819703-056B-4505-8D73-FA6049EB2D55",
    "username":"#######",
    "roleId":15478,
    "status":"Active",
    "firstName":"Joe",
    "lastName":"User",
    "email":"Joe.User@example.net",
    "badgeNumber":"609",
    "language":"en_us",
    "createdOn":"2014-01-06T17:02:43.25Z",
    "updatedOn":"2014-03-13T13:36:37.44Z",
    "lastLoginOn":"2014-03-13T13:36:37.193Z",
    "lastInvitedOn":"2014-01-06T17:02:43.44Z",
    "lastActivatedOn":"2014-03-13T13:36:36.983Z",
    "lastDeactivatedOn":null},
"links":{
    "self":"/api/v1/agencies/d191405f-44c0-423f-8574-fa8b8b4746c8/users/e4b167ba-b244-4c32-9566-00492c6d437e"}},
[1]
    {"type":"user",
    "id":"8cd078f8-1987-470f-accf-004d4e3f1f5a",
"attributes":{
    "externalId":"6200A3ED-83F6-4C2A-8542-DD02691CC297",
    "username":"########",
    "roleId":15478,
    "status":"Active",
    "firstName":"JOHN",
    "lastName":"DOE",
    "email":"john.Doe@Example.net",
    "badgeNumber":"6118",
    "language":"en_us",
    "createdOn":"2014-01-06T17:09:35.69Z",
    "updatedOn":"2014-03-13T13:12:46.51Z",
    "lastLoginOn":"2014-03-13T13:12:46.323Z",
    "lastInvitedOn":"2014-01-06T17:09:35.797Z",
    "lastActivatedOn":"2014-03-13T13:12:46.137Z",
    "lastDeactivatedOn":null},
"links":{
    "self":"/api/v1/agencies/d191405f-44c0-423f-8574-fa8b8b4746c8/users/d98e705a-6e15-45eb-8a2a-30f4b542fe79"}},
```

this repeats with over 1700 items in the attributes node.

I need to pull some data out of those nodes and populate a database I am trying to use this code

```
string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var dict = ser.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
                foreach (var item in dict)
                {
                    Label2.Text = (dict["attributes"]["firstName"]);
                }
```

Just using the Label.Text as a break point to test the code.  The code crashed in the foreach loop with an exception {"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks
Perry

Comment: Have you heard of [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)? Great library to parse and deal with any json data. `JsonObject` will be your friend to find nested items without using Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the thought provoking questions and comments from @Kamo I was able to figure out the answer to my question here is the code for anyone else that may run across this.

```
            {
                //Get the json and convert it to a Dictionary note the new dictionary will contain nested dictionaries
                string json = "However You get it";
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
                //Loop thru the nested Dictionary to get the values you need
                for (int i = 0; i < dict.Values.Sum(x =>x.Count); i++)
                {
                    foreach (var item in dict)
                    {

                        Label2.Text = (dict["data"][i]["attributes"]["firstName"]);

                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are thinking about:

```
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    Label2.Text = (dict.attributes.firstName);
}
```

`firstName` is a property, not a dictionary key. The same is with `attributes`.

EDIT:
Check following code:

```
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    Label2.Text = (dict["attributes"].firstName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either got this exception {"'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'attributes'"}

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the your time to help with this but that resulted in the exception error {"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}

Comment: @Perry Can you say what is `attributes` type?

Comment: when I inspect the dictionary during a run it shows this: {[system.collections.generic dictionary~2[system.string.system object]]}

Comment: Sorry to be a pest but am just getting started with the C# and a nested dictionary. I hope the above response was what you were looking for.  I also tried changing the code to var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json); that did not make any difference.

Comment: One more piece of information that may help:  the dictionary shows {[Data, system.ArrayList]}

Comment: Just wanted clarify the current code.  It is back to what is shown in the original post and the type for the dictionary shows <string, object

Comment: @Perry Now I see it can be completely wrong since you have `data` property. Btw, how can you know you have a dictionary when using `dynamic` as a type?

Comment: I made some more changes I am using this to create the Dictionary var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);.  So I know I am getting a Dictionary.  When the inspect the elements of the dictionary I see it is {[data, System.Collections.ArrayList]}.  I also modified the foreach loop to Label2.Text = (dict["data"][0]["attributes"].firstName);  I no longer get an error message that "attributes" is not a member of the collection but it now shows {"'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'firstName'"

Comment: well I am making some headway this                             Label2.Text = (dict["data"][0]["attributes"]["firstName"]); will retrieve the firstName for the record in the zero index.  So an wrapped the foreach statement in a for loop with the thought being I would increment the index on each loop with this: for (int i = 0; i < dict["data"][i].count; i++).  BUT I now get this weird exception:  {"'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>.count' is inaccessible due to its protection level"}

Comment: Thanks for you time, your comments and example code really helped me to keep digging and come up the solution.  Most likely there would have been another way to do this but I at least figured it.